# Oracle OCI - How to obtain the number of rows in the select set without fetching

Tags: oracle, select, count, row, oracle-call-interface

Noob here (with regards to Oracle and OCI).

I am writing a program to do some tasks for my company.  Amongst the tasks, I have to update an oracle database to keep it in synch with other actions.

I want to pre-allocate memory efficiently to hold the results of fetching on the select set.  In order to do that, I need to know how many rows are in the select set.

I could do it with 2 separate statements; first a SELECT COUNT statement, followed by a SELECT statement, but that is inefficient from a server point of view. I could also just execute my SELECT statement and dynamically allocate memory as rows are fetched from the select set, but that is inefficient from a client point of view.

I want to simply execute the SELECT statement and, before fetching any rows, retrieve the number of matching rows in the select set.

But I cannot locate an attribute that has this information.
There is OCI_ATTR_ROW_COUNT but this is the number of rows FETCHED, not the total number of rows in the select set.
Then there is OCI_ATTR_PARAM_COUNT which tells you the number of COLUMNS (seems useless because you already know how many columns you asked for in your SQL).

Does anybody know how to obtain the select set row count prior to fetching?

Thanks
Josh

Comment: How much data/rows are we talking about?  What is the host language?

Comment: Several answers say there is no way to query the number of rows in the select set.   Thank you for your replies.    Could I work around the problem using a scrollable cursor?   In other words, I know the maximum possible number of rows in the select set (number of rows in the table).  Could I fetch rows out of order starting from the maximum and working down in a binary search fashion until I establish how many rows there are?  Using a binary search algorithm this wouldn't be more than 25 or 30 fetches...

Comment: Our smallest table has 1 row (well actually there are some with 0, but they aren't very interesting), and our largest table has 1.8 Million rows.    Our select sets are expected to generate typically 20 to 50,000 results on a typical table.

Answer (score 5):

You can't.  Oracle the database generally doesn't know how many rows a query will return until after it has fetched the last row.

Normally, the client would be designed to fetch particularly sized batches of data from the client, process those results, and then fetch the next batch of data.  Most PL/SQL GUI applications (TOAD, SQL Developer, etc.) for example, will execute a query, fetch the first batch of 50 or 100 rows, and then wait for the user.  As the user pages through data, the client will fetch the next batch, process that, and iterate until the last batch is consumed.  Whether you can discard the prior batches from memory or whether you need to hold on to them (to support a user's ability to scroll backwards, for example, without re-executing the query) is something that your application would need to determine.

What inefficiency are you worried about when you're concerned about dynamically allocating memory on the client?  That's normally the most efficient way of doing things.  Assuming you pick a reasonable batch size, you'll be requesting reasonably sized chunks of memory on the client (either once or one for each batch depending on whether you need to cache the data locally) which is pretty efficient.

Comment: I see.   Ok, so let me ask a follow up question;  What is happening server side during the OCIStatementExecute function?   I was under the (evidently false) assumption that during this call the server side evaluated all the rows in the subject table for the select criteria and built a result set of the matching rows in memory on the server side for later transmittal to the client during subsequent calls to OCIStatementFetch.      So if thats not what its doing, what IS it doing?

Comment: @Josh - `OCIStatementExecute` sends the query to the database where it is optimized.  A cursor handle is generated that allows the application to request data.  I haven't looked too far under the covers in a while but I would expect that as an optimization the first batch of data is actually returned as well to save the network round-trip of waiting for the first fetch call.  The database generally never materializes the entire result set in memory unless it absolutely has to in order to, say, sort the entire result set.

Comment: @Josh - for more information, you could read up on the parse-execute-fetch steps of processing a SQL statement.  See for example https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:1855700000346846274.  The relevant quote from that post: "execute - we OPEN the statement. For an update, for a delete, for an insert - that would be it, when you OPEN the statement, we execute it. All of the work happens here.  for select it is more complex. Most selects will do ZERO work during the execute. All we are doing is opening the cursor"

Answer (score 2):

By definition, Oracle does not know how many rows there will be in the result set until has finished fetching them all.  Depending on the execution plan used for the query, it may essentially be building the result set row-by-row as you fetch them.

I'd say its unlikely you need to worry about this at all - just allocate memory dynamically.  But I suppose if it is a very big result set you could have some performance issues.

I can think of several options:

1) As you say, do an initial query to count matching rows and use that to allocate memory to hold the full results.

2) Use some technique to perform the query and store its results on the server side, returning the count.  This could be soemthing like a packaged procedure which stores the results in memory, or doing an insert into a working table.  This is probably more work than it is worth unless you have identified a real issue that you need to address.

3) Allocate memory in reasonably-sized chunks based on your expectations of the number of rows likely to be returned.  You may end up overallocating in some cases, but if your chunk size is not too large, that is not likely to be a big concern.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a scrollable Statement Handle and fetch the last row, then ask for the current position :

```
OCIStmtExecute(pOCIServiceHnd, pOCIStmtHnd, pOCIErrorHnd, 0, 0, NULL, NULL,   OCI_STMT_SCROLLABLE_READONLY);

int rowCount = 0;
OCIStmtFetch2(pOCIStmtHnd, pOCIErrorHnd, 1, OCI_FETCH_LAST, 0, OCI_DEFAULT);
OCIAttrGet(pOCIStmtHnd, OCI_HTYPE_STMT, &rowCount, NULL, OCI_ATTR_CURRENT_POSITION, pOCIErrorHnd);
```

Just remember to rewind your Statement Handle if you're going to reuse it :

```
OCIStmtFetch2(pOCIStmtHnd, pOCIErrorHnd, 1, OCI_FETCH_FIRST, 0, OCI_DEFAULT);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it was stated by others Oracle uses producer-consumer design pattern. So result data are NOT kept in any "buffer" but they are generated on-the-fly, when executing OCIStmtFetch. This also relates to SQL optimizer goal (ALL_ROWS, and FIRST_ROWS). For example in Oracle Forms (or other 4GL tools)
most of the complex queries will never reach the end. Users will simply get first page of data displayed and if-and-only-if they scroll down the more rows are returned from the database. This is conceptually very different from Java/Web applications where you have to first get all rows from database and then application sends this whole chunk to the client.

For example PostgreSQL works differently. It uses client's RAM as a buffer. So call to "execute" on statement will wait till ALL result rows are stored in client's RAM. Calling fetch only iterates over the buffer in client's RAM.
(unless you are using explicit cursors).